# What on earth is this background process?

Tags: macos

I found this background process running on my Mac, and I have absolutely no idea what it is. I've looked through activity monitor and can't find it anywhere. I also can't find an installation location for it.

[image: A screenshot of the aforementioned background process.]

I'm running the first public beta of MacOS Ventura on a late 2020 M1 MacBook Pro.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Bear in mind most of us can't read it.

Comment: Nor can I. I'm a native English speaker and only (as far as I'm aware) only use English-language software 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I explore below may well highlight my ignorance of Chinese. I hope that this does not offend anyone and apologise if it does.

You are using the new "Login Items" in System Settings. The (to many of us) unreadable text is the name on the application's developer certificate.

But Ventura and Apple can read the name and translate.  To do this I open your screenshot snippet in a new tab, wait a few seconds for pointer to become an cursor, select the text, ask for translation and there you are:

[image: Screenshot of translation]

The developer is Hao Yunli (according to the translation). Strictly this is the name on the developer certificate which may not obviously be the developer.

That is not the name of the application, so this needs a bit of exploration.

Web search hints that maybe there should be a space as in "Yun Li", in which case you may have one of these apps: [Hao Li in App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/developer/hao-li/id621375881).

Added later: I performed the translation above on a Mac running Ventura beta build 22A5295i. When I repeat this on Monterey 12.4, the translation is "Hao Yun Li" with the extra space.

Alternatively have a look at the `plist` files in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`. Your mysterious app is, most likely, started with one of these.

As a comment on beta software, I feel that the presentation of Launch Agents and Daemons in Login Items leaves something to be desired. For myself I use [LaunchControl](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) to explore and modify such things.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It’s very helpful!